# reading json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following json

```
[{\"Country\":\"Europe\",\"City\":[\"Berlin\",\"Istanbul\",\"London\",\"Manchester\",\"Milan\",\"Paris\"]},null]
```

I want to read the country and its cities.

I have tried it like this

```
var eu = jQuery.parseJSON($("#EU").val());
        for( i=0; i<eu.length();i++)
        {
          alert( eu[0][0]);
          }
```

But I am getting undefined error in alert.

How can I accomplish the above task?

Comment: please show your HTML too... your problem might be in your selector. You'll also have a problem with `alert( eu[0][0]);` anyway as you might want to include `i` somewhere here...

Comment: I guess `eu[0]` is object and you can call `[0]` for it. It should be `eu[0]["Country"]` or `eu[0]["City"]`. I think you want `eu[0]["City"][0]`

Comment: Can you check what `$("#EU").val()` and `jQuery.parseJSON($("#EU").val())` are returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is a property and not a method. Just drop the `()`:

```
for( i=0; i<eu.length;i++) {
  alert( eu[i].Country );
}
```

Furthermore, you have an Array of objects, so `eu[0][0]` does not exists. To output the country, eg., use `eu[0].Country` or `eu[0]['Country']`.

Besides, your second Array element is null, so you should check for that (or receive an error):

```
for( i=0; i<eu.length;i++) {
  if( 'Country' in eu[i] ) {
    alert( eu[i].Country );
  }
}
```

Comment: still giving undefined

Comment: @abc Then probably the way you retrieve the JSON is wrong. Please add the respective HTML for `#EU`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this within the `for` loop :

```
for( i=0; i<eu.length;i++)
{
  alert( eu[0]['Country']);
  alert( eu[0]['City'][0]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if `#EU` is an `form input` it will get the json, if its a `div` or html element try `text()` to get the json

```
$("#EU").text();
```

and the fix the loop

```
for( var i=0, x = eu.length; i < x; i++) //length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code which is much simpler.

```
var vJson = [{"Country":"Europe","City":["Berlin","Istanbul","London","Manchester","Milan","Paris"]}];

$.each(vJson, function(idx, obj) { 
    alert(obj.Country); // Get Country
    $.each(obj.City, function(idx1, obj1) { 
        alert(obj1); // Get multiple city of country
    });
});
```